# Passing LocaleTimeString to input type=time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the current time to a  box  what am I missing

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var current = new Date();
  var time = new Date(current);
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString('EN-US');
}
```

```html
<h1 id="timer"></h1>

<input id="timer" name="timer" type="time">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `id` must be unique. The first element encountered with the id will be used to set the value. In your case the `h1` is encountered first and the value is set.
2. The time should be a `24 hour format`. No need to convert to locale string. `new Date()` construction will give the date in the client's locale.
3. The value is set by `value` attribute of the  element, not by using `innerHTML`.
4. While setting the value it must be in the format `hh:mm` or `hh:mm:ss`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var current = new Date();
  var hours = current.getHours(), minutes = current.getMinutes(), seconds = current.getSeconds();
  var time = (hours<10?'0':'')+hours+":"+
              (minutes<10?'0':'')+minutes+":"+
              (seconds<10?'0':'')+seconds;
  document.getElementById("timer").value = time;
  console.log(document.getElementById("timer").value);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="timertext"></h1>

<input id="timer" name="timer" type="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** your `ID` should be unique for each element.

**Second** you cannot use `innerHTML`. You need to use `value`.

**Third** your time should be a 24 hour format to work in chrome. You can use a 12 hour format if its firefox. [Read it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/timehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var current = new Date();
  var time = new Date(current);
  document.getElementById("timer-h1").innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString('EN-US');
  document.getElementById("timer").value = "22:53:05";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="timer-h1"></h1>

<input id="timer" name="timer" type="time">
```